# When clearing another class' attribute in another class why would it not work?

Tags: python

I am writing a function to load a previously saved game in chess using `Pygame`. I have six classes: `main2, GUI2, navigation2, calc, board and pieces`. I store the attribute that stores where each chess piece is on the board class like so:

```
class board:
def __init__(self,main):
    self.main = main
    self.pieces = self.main.pieces
    self.prv_pos = []
    self.dict = self.pieces.dict
    A = ["bRook","bKnight","bBishop","bQueen","bKing","bBishop","bKnight","bRook"]
    B = ["bPawn","bPawn","bPawn","bPawn","bPawn","bPawn","bPawn","bPawn"]
    C = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"wKing"]
    D = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    E = [0,0,0,0,"wQueen",0,0,0]
    F = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    G = ["wPawn","wPawn","wPawn","wPawn","wPawn","wPawn","wPawn","wPawn"]
    H = ["wRook","wKnight","wBishop","wQueen",0,"wBishop","wKnight","wRook"]
    self.piece_pos= [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H]
```

I also have a class called main that is passed an instance on each class possible thus all my objects interact with each other through the main class. Thus in my navigation class that hosts the functions to save and load the game I wrote this:

```
class navigation:
def __init__(self,GUI):
    self.GUI = GUI
    self.main = self.GUI.main
    self.piece_pos = self.GUI.main.board.piece_pos
    self.GUI.draw_button("save",self.GUI.SQ_DIM*8,self.GUI.SQ_DIM)
    self.GUI.draw_button("load",self.GUI.SQ_DIM*8,self.GUI.SQ_DIM*3)
    self.GUI.draw_button("exit",self.GUI.SQ_DIM*8,self.GUI.SQ_DIM*5)

def game_save(self):
    file = open("Save file.txt","w")
    for line in self.piece_pos:
        for item in line:
            file.write(str(item)+",")
        file.write("\n")
    file.close()

def game_load(self): #WIP
    self.piece_pos = []
    self.GUI.draw_board()
```

As you may notice that the `game_load` function is pretty empty; that is because I wanted to check that in the `self.piece_pos = []` line that the attribute is actually cleared throughout the classes. But when I call the `self.GUI.draw_board()` function which just draws the current board positions which are stored in `piece_pos` in the class board the board's appearance in the GUI is the same. I expect an error message in the python shell telling me there is no `self.piece_pos[i][j]` but it seems to me that the attribute hasn't changed whatsoever.

The function for `draw_board()` is stored in the class `'GUI'`.

```
def draw_board(self):
    X = 0
    Y = 0
    Ycounter = False
    sqcounter = False
    #Draw the board
    print("GUI update")
    for i in range(0,8):
        for j in range(0,8):
            print()
            print("Piece at:")
            print(i,j)
            print(self.main.piece_at(i,j))
            pg.draw.rect(self.window, self.sq_colour[i][j],(X,Y,self.SQ_DIM,self.SQ_DIM),0)
            if self.main.piece_at(i,j) == 0:
                print("square empty")
                pass
            else:
                print("square occupied")
                self.window.blit(self.dict[self.main.piece_at(i,j)],(X,Y))

            #Change of X coord
            if X >(self.SQ_DIM*6):
                X = 0
                Ycounter = True
                sqcounter = True
            else:
                X +=(self.SQ_DIM)

            #Change of Y coord
            if Ycounter == True:
                Y +=self.SQ_DIM
                Ycounter = False
            else:
                pass
```

So I have come to the conclusions that I am not understanding something about how to globalize the `piece_pos` attribute. But I don't know how to solve this conundrum? Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in `game_load()`, `self.piece_pos` refers to `navigation.piece_pos`, while `draw_board()` uses the object referenced by `GUI.main.board.piece_pos`.

You're effectively doing this

```
a = [5]
b = a
print(a, b)   # prints [5] [5]

# By reassigning `b` you only change what it refers to,
# it doesn't affect what it used to refer to before.
b = []
print(a, b)   # prints [5] []

# Instead, if you make an *in-place* modification, then the underlying
# object will indeed change, as both names refer to the same object.
a = b = [5]
b.append(3)
print(a, b)  # prints [5, 3] [5, 3]
```

If you really want to make a change, it should be

```
def game_load(self): #WIP
    self.main.board.piece_pos = []
    self.GUI.draw_board()
```

Since the `navigation` class is a wrapper of GUI, it might be best to get rid of `self.piece_pos` and use function calls to get/set the piece positions, e.g.,

```
def get_piece_pos(self):
    return self.main.board.piece_pos

def set_piece_pos(self, new_pos):
    self.main.board.piece_pos = new_pos
```

Overall though, I don't see the point of this class. The save/load/exit buttons belong to the GUI, as should the respective save/load functions. I would just integrate this functionality in the GUI class, as this is the object the user interacts with.